# Blackberry Playbook signing keys

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-playbook

I lost the developer signing keys for the playbook in a hard drive crash. I tried applying for [new keys](https://www.blackberry.com/SignedKeys/codesigning.html), but have not got a reply back. Tried to mail them too but no reply. Is there a way to get signing keys in 2020 for the playbook?
I believe Blackberry team monitors stackoverflow for legacy support.. Hope they can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your inbox and spam folder for the BlackBerry PlayBook signing keys now. There were some requests that were held up that have been processed now.

Comment: Hi @MSohm 
Very surprised that a BB representative still supports BB10 / PB enthusiasts. 
Basically, I have the same issue as OP but now is March 2021. Is it possible to get two .csj files nowadays? I posted a request, received a reply from webmaster@rim.com , Order number 176705652, asked for help at devsupport@rim.com but still no email with the keys. Please help

Comment: I recommend using the first method on the form, where you sign in with your BlackBerry ID to download your BlackBerry ID Token.  This will allow you to use it right away instead of waiting for a .csj file (which often get caught in spam filters).

Comment: wow, thanks for responding so promptly. I did get the keys!
Regarding the second part of your comment, yes, it works in this way for BB10 dev environment while the Blackberry Tablet OS Deployment Wizard insists on uploading 2 .csj-files. Either way, thank you for all your assistance. Still have ~10 months before 01/04/2022 to develop something cool.